# Multiple component renders in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a custom hook to fetch data and pass it to a component. However, the component ends up rendering multiple times (going beyond 100), as shown in the image below

[image]

This is the component that consumes the custom hook (userId) is a prop that is handed down from the parent component

```
export default function AuthorDetails({ userId }) {
  const { articleAuthor, authorError, authorLoading } = useGetAuthor(userId);

  return (
    <div className="authordetails__container">
      <div className="authorDetails__content">
        {console.log(articleAuthor)}
        {authorLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {articleAuthor && (
          <p>
            <span>{articleAuthor.author}</span>
            {articleAuthor.twitter && (
              <span>
                <img src={twittericon} alt="twitter" />
              </span>
            )}
            {articleAuthor.facebook && (
              <span>
                <img src={facebookicon} alt="facebook" />
              </span>
            )}
            {articleAuthor.website && (
              <span>
                <img src={websiteicon} alt="website" />
              </span>
            )}
          </p>
        )}
        {authorError && <p>{authorError}</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the code for the custom hook

```
export default function useGetAuthor(userId) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [articleAuthor, setArticleAuthor] = useState();
  const [authorError, setAuthorError] = useState();
  const [authorLoading, setAuthorLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getAuthor() {
      try {
        setAuthorLoading(true);
        if (currentUser && currentUser.id === userId) {
          setArticleAuthor(currentUser);
          setAuthorLoading(false);
        } else {
          const data = await database.users.doc(userId).get();
          setArticleAuthor(database.formatDocument(data));
          setAuthorLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setAuthorLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
        setAuthorError("Something went wrong! Please refresh to try again");
      }
    }
    getAuthor();
  });

  return { articleAuthor, authorLoading, authorError };
}
```

Comment: First off, you are console logging in the render return as an unintentional side-effect, the render is to be a pure function, so any number of console logs you are seeing isn't an accurate measure of component rendering. You first need to console log correctly within the React component lifecycle, i.e. move the `console.log(articleAuthor)` into a `useEffect` *without* the dependency so you log once per `useEffect` call per render cycle, ***then*** track how many unexpected rerenders occur.

Comment: @DrewReese I have placed the `console.log(articleAuthor)` in the useEffect without the dependency. It does indeed show that the component is rendering multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your useEffect call doesn't specify any dependencies it will run every time the component renders, and every state update will trigger a new render. Add `currentUser` as a dependency:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function getAuthor() {
      try {
        setAuthorLoading(true);
        if (currentUser && currentUser.id === userId) {
          setArticleAuthor(currentUser);
          setAuthorLoading(false);
        } else {
          const data = await database.users.doc(userId).get();
          setArticleAuthor(database.formatDocument(data));
          setAuthorLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setAuthorLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
        setAuthorError("Something went wrong! Please refresh to try again");
      }
    }
    getAuthor();
  }, [currentUser]);
```

Comment: The hook runs every render and should be fixed as shown above but, it's not causing the 100 renders. I think there's something up the tree causing AuthorDetails to re-render over and over.

Comment: Tried it, but I am still getting multiple renders with the currentUser as a dependency as well as when I include both currentUser and userId in the dependency array.

Comment: @nlta I managed to trace the problem high up in the component tree as indicated. Turns out one of the parent components using hooks needed me to include a dependency array, but I didn't, which caused it to render multiple times causing the child components to rerender as well. Thank you

Comment: @AlexMasinde Nice! It's worth trying out a linter like ESLint (rule is called exhaustive-deps). This particular issue is super easy for a linter to spot and on the flip side can be very hard to track down in a large project.